# How can I install WMI for working in Ubuntu with PHP?

Tags: php, ubuntu, wmi

I need to consult the computers in my network, certain information that is available through WMI.

The server where the service will be in Ubuntu, so I need to find something similar to get the information already mentioned.

If I can make this code work I can go from there.

```
<?php
    $pc = "192.168.1.4"; //IP of the PC to manage

    $WbemLocator = new COM ("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
    $WbemServices = $WbemLocator->ConnectServer($pc, 'root\\cimv2', 'your account', 'your password');
    $WbemServices->Security_->ImpersonationLevel = 3;

    $disks =    $WbemServices->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");

    foreach ($disks as $d)
    {
        $str=sprintf("%s (%s) %s bytes, %4.1f%% free\n", $d->Name,$d->VolumeName,number_format($d->Size,0,'.',','), $d->FreeSpace/$d->Size*100.0);

        echo $str;
    }
?>
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found

Comment: Did you install the COM extension? https://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

Comment: @ceejayoz Doesn't that require Windows?

Comment: @Jonnix Probably, which would be a bit of an obstacle to OP.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hi, I tried but I could not do it in a Ubuntu enviroment.

Comment: @RafaelArias As Jonnix pointed out, you may need Windows for this.